# All Macro-Enabled Excel Worksheets End Up Corrupt

Tags: excel, vba, corruption

Any time I enable the macro below, the worksheet corrupts.
I have copied and pasted my data into a brand new book.

Upon saving and re-opening, I receive the "Do you want to attempt to recover as much as we can?" dialog, and the formatting on the macro-enabled sheet is reset, and the macro disabled.

I see this in the VBA editor, which appears like "Sheet 2" is being treated as some unknown object, and gives "First Article" another sheet variable.

[image]

Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        Dim vars As Variant
        vars = Array("<CLICK FOR VARIANT LIST>", "sensitive content hidden")

        Dim sVars As String
        sVars = Join(vars, ",")

        With Range("E6").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=sVars
        End With

        vars = Array("NOT SET", "SET")
        sVars = Join(vars, ",")

        With Range("I6").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=sVars
        End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vars As Variant
    vars = Array("<CLICK FOR VARIANT LIST>", "sensitive content hidden")

    If Target.Address = Range("E6").Address Then
        Dim i As Integer
        i = Application.Match(Range("E6").Value, vars, False)
        If i = 1 Then
            Range("A11:A109").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("D111:D112").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Range("A11:A109").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("D111:D112").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("A1").Value = i + 6
        End If

        'SXM/HD
        If i = 0 _
        Or Range("E6").Value = "sensitive content hidden" Then
            Range("hd_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("hd_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("sxm_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("sxm_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Range("hd_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("hd_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("sxm_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("sxm_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        'DAB
        If i = 0 _
        Or Range("E6").Value = "sensitive content hidden"
        Then
            Range("dab_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("dab_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("dab_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Range("dab_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("dab_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("dab_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        'GPS
        If i = 0 _
        Or Range("E6").Value = "sensitive content hidden"
        Then
            Range("gps_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("gps_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("gps_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Range("gps_sw_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("gps_pn_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("gps_function_row").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - correct, I did not notice that

Comment: Copy the code to a new workbook, and burn this one. Where is this code written in, specifically? This `Worksheet_Change` handler looks like it could be re-entrant; toggle `Application.EnableEvents` off to avoid that (and back on after handling the `Worksheet.Change` event.

Comment: I copied all my data into a new workbook.  I tried toggling EnableEvents and the workbook still corrupts, even with everything deleted after the first "If" block in Worksheet_Change.  This happens on two machines, so it has to be something in my code.

Comment: And that's all the code there is? Which worksheet module is it written in? `Sheet2`?

Comment: Also, does the workbook still get corrupted if all the code is commented-out?

Comment: Yep, that's all the code there is.  Written in Sheet2, but after I save and re-open Sheet2 apparently renames itself to Sheet3.  No, the workbook is not corrupted if I comment out the code.  I think I narrowed it down to the Variant data type I am using.  I am still debugging, but for some reason removing that line does not result in a corrupt document...